# Django redirect user only once in session

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I need to redirect the user only once, depending on the user agent.

In middleware.py I have:

```
class UserAgentDetectMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        if get_response is not None:
            self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        self.process_request(request)
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user_agent = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user_agent(request))
        if request.user_agent.is_pc:
            request.template_prefix = ''
        else:
            request.template_prefix = 'mobile_'
```

in views.py :

```
class UserAgentIndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_template_names(self):
        try:
            template_name = os.path.join(self.request.template_prefix + 'index.html')
        except TemplateDoesNotExist:
            template_name = 'index.html'
        return [template_name]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        ...
```

So, if users device is PC, `template_name` is `index.html`, otherwise it's `mobile_index.html`.

But now if users device is mobile, django redirects user to mobile version of the page every time. But user should have ability to go to the desktop version of the site. How to fix it?

Thanks for your time and help.